# MySQL - Is hexadecimal

Tags: mysql, hex

How could I check if a varchar code is hexadecimal in MySQL?

Something like a ISHEX() function:

```
 ISHEX('QWERT') // false
 ISHEX('12345') // true
 ISHEX('ABCDE') // true
 ISHEX('i+5=G') // false
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using the REGEXP operator?

```
SELECT 'QWERT' REGEXP '^[0-9ABCDEF]+$'; -- 0
SELECT '12345' REGEXP '^[0-9ABCDEF]+$'; -- 1
SELECT 'ABCDE' REGEXP '^[0-9ABCDEF]+$'; -- 1
SELECT 'i+5=G' REGEXP '^[0-9ABCDEF]+$'; -- 0
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't know so much about regular expressions, Can I write [0-9A-F] instead?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has a cool little function called [UNHEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex).

I haven't tried this, but for someone who wants to give it a shot and avoid regular expressions, you can use this:

```
SELECT !ISNULL(UNHEX('your string')); -- returns 0 since it failed unhexing
SELECT !ISNULL(UNHEX('AF0B')); -- returns 1 since it succeeded
```